# Syntax error when using Aptana Studio with php project

Tags: php, aptana

I am trying to open a working project in php with Aptana 3 but I keep getting error messages about [] . This is the code that aptana is complaining about:

```
render("../templates/buy_search.php", ["title" => "Buy"] );
```

It is complaining for the opening [ and it says Syntax error. No idea why it is giving the error because the project works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
render("../templates/buy_search.php", ["title" => "Buy"] );
```

Should be

```
render("../templates/buy_search.php", array("title" => "Buy"));
```

For all versions of PHP prior to **5.4**

Comment: Thanks that apparently was the problem. If you do not mind me asking since I am new to php why is the project working fine with [] but aptana wants array();

Comment: Actually `["title" => "Buy"]` is not proper PHP syntax to define or pass an array to a function, that is the issue. No PHP code will accept it like that

Comment: Except php 5.4 which supported the this syntax. `As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. `. However you editor/IDE may not like this :)